# How to make string pass from onclick to a function?

Tags: javascript

My string is like this

```
sakjgbsd aksdg's ad asidg's iasudgbsb
```

but when i print the string in function it prints only

```
 sakjgbsd aksdg
```

the part after (') is not printing

here is how i send data

```
<a href='#' data-status='" + data[i][col[j]] + "' " +
                            "onclick='submit(this)'>Click Here</a>
```

here is Function

```
function submit(str) 
{
var status = $(str).attr("data-status");
alert(status)
}
```

Comment: _the part after (') is not printing_ `'` show closing/ending of string.

Comment: why should it throw error?

Answer (score 1):

Change your string to

```
`sakjgbsd aksdg's ad asidg's iasudgbsb` // backticks (sign under tilde ~)
```

or

```
"sakjgbsd aksdg's ad asidg's iasudgbsb"
```

Comment: In English, it's `tilde`.

Comment: That's not an error BTW. That's just a different language.